# CiviMail Deadlock Issue

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, deadlocks

I am facing deadlock on civicrm_acl_cache.
I am sending email to 400,000 users.
Many times, deadlock occur and due to system lock website goes down.

Need help from team

Comment: Do you have logging turned on at admin - system settings - misc? Try turning it off?

Comment: logging was off, but still it goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing CiviCRM 5.13.1 and enabling multiple MySQL locks. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13854 for details.

Comment: Thanks, I will update and analyze system behaviour after upgrade